# Any quick ways to declare variables faster in SAPUI5

Tags: eclipse, sapui5

I have to type sap.ui.commons... so many times when declaring. is there any way to short this process like in Netbean, when i type "sout" and press tab. It automatically generates system.out.println();
thanks!

Comment: Use XMLViews, and declare a short, one-letter namespace for your various control libraries

Comment: Voting to close since [_SAPUI5 Tools for Eclipse_ is **abandoned**](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/609fd015eaf64bd2a4a5c0331590eb4c) by SAP due to a low number of users and high maintenance costs. This question is less likely to help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Install the [sapui5-plugin](https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#sapui5). 
It adds many templates to your eclipse, so eg. to get a `sap.ui.commons.Button` you can type "but" and hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>space</kbd> to get the code-templates.

Here you can see the templates:
[image: templates]

The upper options (with the green C) only extend to the name:
[image: name extended]

The lower options extend to a complete template with the parameters that this object can have:
[image: object template]